# No suitable constructor found for LwjglApplication(TheGame,LwjglApplicationConfiguration)

Tags: android, libgdx

After a successful build Android Studio says when I try to start my libGDX project with DesktopLauncher:

```
Gradle: error: no suitable constructor found for LwjglApplication(TheGame,LwjglApplicationConfiguration)
constructor LwjglApplication.LwjglApplication(ApplicationListener,LwjglApplicationConfiguration) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; TheGame cannot be converted to ApplicationListener)
constructor LwjglApplication.LwjglApplication(ApplicationListener,Canvas) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; TheGame cannot be converted to ApplicationListener)
```

It is more than strange after a build with zero warning/error.

Comment: This part of the error seems relevant: `TheGame cannot be converted to ApplicationListener`

Comment: But project is without error and warning.

Comment: Studio is probably not building everything you think its building?  What is printing the error you are seeing?  (The error looks like a javac compiler error to me.)

Comment: Project is errorless, these errors appear, when I try to run desktop project.